# "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" with partial personalized TOC (titletoc)

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I would like that each chapter starts with a personalized partial TOC (I did this with titletoc).

When I compile I got the following error :

> something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

I've done a MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt, 
               a4paper, 
               twoside]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Package import
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, 
            bottom=2.5cm, 
            inner=2.5cm, 
            outer=3cm, 
            twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,               
            dvipsnames]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{titletoc}               
\usepackage[hidelinks,
            colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = PineGreen,
            urlcolor = PineGreen,
            citecolor = PineGreen,
            anchorcolor = PineGreen, 
            allcolors = PineGreen]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfiles}              
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Redefine TOC Style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\Large\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{BrickRed}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{BrickRed}} % Chapter number
{\color{BrickRed}}  
{\hfill\color{BrickRed}\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsubsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\small} % Spacing and font options for subsubsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsubsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
{
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
}
%\subfile{test}

\startcontents[Introduction]
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap-introduction}
{
    \hrulefill
    \printcontents[Introduction]{}{1}{}
    \vspace{-3mm}
    \hrulefill
}
\section{Context}\label{sec-context}
This chapter introduces the context of the project
\stopcontents[Introduction]
\end{document}
```

I've already investigate a little and this error appears when there is something to print before the partial TOC (in this case) the first `\hrulefill`. If there is directly the `\printcontents` command there is no error.

If I remove the personalized TOC style there is no error.

And I have already used this style (without the partial toc) in others documents and it works just fine ...

The error redirects me toward the main.ptc file which contains the following :

```
\babel@toc {english}{}
\ttl@starttoc {Introduction@1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{2}{chapter.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Context}{2}{section.1.1}%
\ttl@stoptoc {Introduction@1}
\contentsfinish
```

Does any of you have an idea, where it can come from ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `\hrulefill\par` before `\printcontents`.

Comment: Thanks  it did the work :)